# Difference between oauth2/v2 vs oidc Spotify API

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, spotify, uno-platform

i'm currently trying to connect via UNO-Plattform sample to the Spotify API.
https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/blob/master/UI/Authentication.OidcDemo/Authentication.OidcDemo/Authentication.OidcDemo.Shared/MainPage.xaml.cs

Therefore I have updated the PrepareClient method.

```
private async void PrepareClient()
{
    var redirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().OriginalString;

            // Create options for endpoint discovery
    var options = new OidcClientOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://accounts.spotify.com", //"https://demo.duendesoftware.com/",
        ClientId = "7c1....a45",
        ClientSecret = "4b..a",
        Scope = "playlist-read-private",
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,                
        ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,
        Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode
    };

    // Create the client. In production application, this is often created and stored
    // directly in the Application class.
    _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
    var extra_parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //extra_parameters.Add("response_type", "token"); // if i add this line i get an error

    _loginState = await _oidcClient.PrepareLoginAsync(extra_parameters);
    btnSignin.IsEnabled = true;

    // Same for logout url.
    //If i add this line a get an error
    //_logoutUrl = new Uri(await _oidcClient.PrepareLogoutAsync(new LogoutRequest()));
    btnSignout.IsEnabled = true;
}

private async void SignIn_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var startUri = new Uri(_loginState.StartUrl);

    // Important: there should be NO await before calling .AuthenticateAsync() - at least
    // on WebAssembly, in order to prevent triggering the popup blocker mechanisms.
    var userResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri);

    if (userResult.ResponseStatus != WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        txtAuthResult.Text = "Canceled";
        // Error or user cancellation
        return;
    }

    // User authentication process completed successfully.
    // Now we need to get authorization tokens from the response
    var authenticationResult = await _oidcClient.ProcessResponseAsync(userResult.ResponseData, _loginState);

    if (authenticationResult.IsError)
    {
        var errorMessage = authenticationResult.Error;
        // TODO: do something with error message
        txtAuthResult.Text = $"Error {errorMessage}";
        return;
    }

    // That's completed. Here you have to token, ready to do something
    var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    var refreshToken = authenticationResult.RefreshToken;

    // TODO: make something useful with the tokens
    txtAuthResult.Text = $"Success, token is {token}";
}
```

If i use Postman for authentication, i can use the URL

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=7c...45&scope=playlist-read-private&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&state=test'
```

and everything works fine and i get the token in the callback url as parameter.

If i add as "extra_parameters" the "response_type" : "token" i get the message, that this parameter is not supported...

I'm a little bit stucked here and don't know how to proceed.

I'm happy about any help in every direction to get this autentication done with uno-plattform.

Answer (score 1):

OIDC can be described as a superset of OAuth2. It is a way for an identity provider to issue tokens and supply info about a user via additional APIs. Read more [here](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect).

The Oidc code that you use (probably `IdentityModel.OidcClient`?) requires a the service you’re calling to implement a few extra endpoints which Spotify has not implemented for their API. This is discussed in [this forum topic](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Scopes-listed-at-well-known-oidc-configuration-aren-t-accepted/td-p/5264875). Because of the missing Oidc support, your code will try making calls that do not work.

The [SpotifyAPI-NET library](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/) might also help you authenticate and make API calls instead.